# after my visitors log in using Facebook connect, they need to log again when clicking on a like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm developping a contest for my website.
http://www.abcroisiere.com?jeu=1

People can subscrire using Facebook connect. At the last page of the contest you can click on a like button.
But the visitor has to log in again in Facebook for that. Is it normal ? Is there something I'm missing ?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

If the user was logged out of Facebook, goes to your site, and logs in to Facebook via the Login button on your site, the Like button won't be aware of that, so will still think the user needs to log in before they can complete the Like action

If this edge case is important to your app; refresh or replace the Like button after the user logs in. When it refreshes it will be aware of the user's login and won't prompt the login dialog if the user clicks it

Comment: ok thank you, we'll try it. I wil post an update if it's work.